# Can I change the camera aperture value on my Honor 8 phone?

Tags: aperture, macro, cameraphones

I am planning to do some macro photography with my Honor 8 phone, 
i got a macro lens to clip over the phone.

the problem is, i need more depth of field and hence i need to increase the f-number, the default camera app of the phone has "pro" mode and it allows to change, shutter speed, ISO, WB, metering and focusing, but not the aperture.

does anyone know how to change aperture in default camera application, or does know any other application which allows it.i tried to look in play store to try different apps but none allowed to change aperture,

is it even possible or supported by hardware/OS that aperture value can be changed?

Comment: Many phones do not have an adjustable aperture at all.

Comment: is there any possible way (website/forum) to find out if my phone (honor 8) has it or not?

Comment: [This link](https://www.gsmarena.com/honor_8_pro-review-1604p9.php) (and multiple others from google) talks about the variable aperture _effect_ and mentions the data from the dual camera setup is used to create depth map

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'd suggest asking a new question: "How can I get more depth of field for macro photography with a smartphone camera?"

Comment: @suvartheec yes, i understand that, but since i am using macro lens, i wont be able to use both of the cameras of my phone due to design of the lens, the link you mentioned and what i found on the google mostly is about cell phones are going in the direction to achieve shallow depth of field effect and not the great depth of field

Comment: @mattdm ok, i think that that makes sense, i will ask another question, thanks

Comment: @maxchirag Keep in mind the answer might be "you can't, really". Sometimes that's how things are.

Comment: Even if you could stop it down, to get to a setting that you would probably want would end up requiring a *lot* more light... then you'd be asking about how to get a macro ring light hooked up to your smartphone (or why the ISO noise was so bad now...).  There really is a limit to how far you can push a tiny sensor and lens.

Comment: Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a [speedbooster, focal reducer or telecompressor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telecompressor) available for a cellphone.

Answer (score 9):

Camera phones don't have variable apertures (apart from a handful exceptions) because they are not designed like full sized cameras. Owing to their tiny size, decreasing thickness of phones in general and the ever present cost-vs-complexity challenge, they have a fixed opening/aperture.

If the bundled camera app doesn't provide you any option to change the aperture, in all probability it doesn't support that physically. Hence external third party apps might not be of great help.

Not sure if this will work but you can maybe try to increase the distance from subject (which will increase the hyperfocal distance/depth of field) and then digitally zoom (i.e. crop and enlarge). Phones mostly have the digital zoom feature and high resolution. So cropping and enlarging might not take away a lot of quality. Just a thought, not sure if that would actually work.